# Adding a row to table causes elements in theader to move into tbody

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to append a row to a table.

HTML:

```html
<table class="table" id="main-profiles">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Address</th>
      <th scope="col">Mount point</th>
      <th scope="col">Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

JQuery:

```js
const row = $('tr')
  .append(`<th scope="row">${++index}</th>`)
  .append(`<td>${profile.name}</td>`)
  .append(`<td><code>${profile.address + ':' + profile.port}<code></td>`)
  .append(`<td><code>${profile.mountPoint}</code></td>`)
  .append(`<td><p>placeholder</p></td>`)

$('#main-profiles').append(row)
```

The problem is when the code run, the content of `<tr>` in `<thead>` magically get into the `<tbody>`. Here is a screenshot of how it looks:

[image: how the structure looks like]

Is this some bug or a mistake I made? I need guidance.

Comment: you meant to create a new row right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two issues causing the problem. The first is that `$('tr')` is *selecting* a row, not creating a new one. The `tr` that's selected is the one in the `thead` which you then `append()` to the body of the table, hence the element appears to move. You should instead use `$('<tr />')` to *create* a new row. Secondly you need to `append()` the new row in to the `tbody` of the  table.

Also note that as you're using a template literal you can avoid the making multiple `append()` calls. Try this:

```js
let index = 0;
let profile = {
  name: 'Foo Bar',
  address: '1 Any Street',
  port: 8080,
  mountPoint: 'Lorem ipsum'
}

const row = $('<tr />').append(`
  <th scope="row">${++index}</th>
  <td>${profile.name}</td>
  <td><code>${profile.address + ':' + profile.port}<code></td>
  <td><code>${profile.mountPoint}</code></td>
  <td><p>placeholder</p></td>`);

$('#main-profiles tbody').append(row)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="main-profiles">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Address</th>
      <th scope="col">Mount point</th>
      <th scope="col">Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: good answer,  just want to add a reference: https://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 1):

You want to attach to the tbody, not to the head I'm assuming.  Your css selector is selecting the first tr row it sees, in the thead.  I took the liberty of turning your template string into one string.  No need to use so many appends.

```js
index=1
profile = { name: 'name', address: 'add', port: 'port', 'mountPoint': 'mp' };

const row = $('#main-profiles tbody')
  .append(`<tr><th scope="row">${++index}</th>
<td>${profile.name}</td>
<td><code>${profile.address + ':' + profile.port}<code></td>
<td><code>${profile.mountPoint}</code></td>
<td><p>placeholder</p></td></tr>`)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="main-profiles">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Address</th>
      <th scope="col">Mount point</th>
      <th scope="col">Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```